# Есть смысловая разница между несовер. и совер. деепричастиями?

Tags: семантика, части-речи

> Атлет прибыл в Португалию в очень
> хорошей форме, выиграв пять боев
> подряд ***соревновавшись*** / ***соревнуясь*** в известных
> чемпионатах.

Меняется ли смысл, если менять деепричастие с совершенного на несовершенное? У меня есть ощущение, что совершенное деепричастие почти никогда не употребляется (сеяв, жалев, читав), а если и употребляется, то может быть заменено несовершенным без потери смысла. К примеру:

> ***Учившись*** во многих школах, он многое постиг.
>
> ***Учась*** во многих школах, он многое постиг.

Answer (score 2):

1) Совершенный вид: действие, выраженное деепричастием, не совпадает (смещено) по времени с действием, выраженным глаголом (обычно предшествует ему):

Все слушали, и дивились его речам, и спрашивали друг друга, откуда он, не учившись, знает все это. Учившись в пансионе, например, она решительно не понимала ни второй части арифметики, ни грамматики.

Сравнить: Учась в пансионе, она не понимала... (не понимала во время учения). Учившись в пансионе, она не понимала... (хотя она раньше училась в пансионе, она не понимала (сейчас)...

2) Несовершенный вид: действие, выраженное деепричастием, совпадает по времени с действием, выраженным глаголом: А Билл Гейтс, между прочим, тоже придумал первую свою программу, ещё учась в школе. Замечу кстати, что, учась в гимназии, я имел по-латыни всегда пятерки.

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ

Вообще-то "правильные" глаголы образуют деепричастия в соответствии с видом: от глагола НВ - деепричастие НВ с помощью суффикса А/Я по схеме: учиться - учатся -  учась; от глагола СВ - деепричастие СВ с помощью суффикса В/ВШИ по схеме: выучить - выучил - выучив, выучиться - выучился - выучившись.

Тогда форма "учившись" - "НЕПРАВИЛЬНАЯ", тем не менее ею пользуются, хотя и не часто. Возможно, это связано с тем, что семантика деепричастных У форм "учась - учившись" разная, и деепричастие НВ "учившись" все-таки может выразить смещение времен, как и деепричастие СВ.

А вот "неправильная" форма "соревновавшись" в текстах (Нацкорпус) и вовсе отсутствует, следовательно, ее применять не следует.

Answer (score 2):

У вас все деепричастия (соревновавшись, соревнуясь, учась, учившись) — несовершенного вида. Вы путаете вид и время.

Answer (score 2):

Niemand прав. Соревноваться и учиться - глаголы несов. вида, от них образуются деепричастия несовершенного вида.

russkiyyazik.ru:
Нек-рые глаголы несов. вида образуют Д. (обычно при употреблении с отрицанием) от основы прош. времени присоединением суффиксов -в/-вши (быв и бывши, знав и знавши, ехав и ехавши, имев и имевши, а также пахавши, лизавши, вязнувши). Такие Д. имеют разг. или прост. стилистическую окраску и обычно малоупотребительны.

Потому Вы и засомневались, что у них одинаковый вид, только соревновавшись и учившись - разговорные формы, а учась и соревнуясь - литературная норма.

http://russkiyyazik.ru/226/

Comment: Рассмотрим пример из ответа @Vera: "*Учившись* в пансионе, она не понимала грамматики." Здесь есть ощущение, что действие "учившись" **предшествует** "понимала". Если же использовать "учась", будет ощущение **одновременности** во времени. Соответствует это литературным нормам или нет, такое ощущения есть в разговорной речи.

Answer (score 0):

Автор вопроса действительно спутал вид и время, поэтому и ответы были не на его вопрос. Но вопрос-то понятен.

Попробую ответить. 
В русском языке деепричастия не имеют категории времени и для бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида образуются регулярно только от глагольных основ настоящего времени (зная, уча, хлебая). Все эти причастия несовершенного вида, категория времени отсутствует. Деепричастия совершенного вида означают действие уже совершенное к моменту деуствия основного глагола, совершенного вида - действия к этому моменту законченные.

Причастия на -а(-я) - это деепричастия несовершенного вида.

Деепричастия на в(ши)- можно классифицировать как причастия совершенного вида, а в некоторых случаях причастия на "вши" сохранили рудиментарные свойства перфекта (исторически они означали действие совершенное непосредственно перед действием основного глагола).

Глаголы с возвратным суффиксом подчиняются общим правилам за исключением того, что суффикс "ши" для совершенного вида они как правило не теряют. Историческое противопоставление по значению деепричастий на -в и -вши для возвратных глаголов не актуально.

О правилах образования деепричастий обоих видов - ниже.

Деепричастия от глагольных основ прошедшего времени бесприставочных глаголов (знав(ши), учив(ши), хлебав(ши)), включая возвратные, в основном считаются устаревшими и/или просторечными. Тем не менее такие причастия, как и все причастия на "в(ши)" можно классифицировать как причастия совершенного вида.

Бесприставочные глаголы совершенного вида и двухвидовые глаголы совершенного вида образуют деепричастия совершенного вида на -в(ши) по тем же правилам:  (решив(ши), решившись, женив(ши), женившись) - все эти формы нормативны (кроме устаревших на "-ши").

Приставочные глаголы обычно имеют самостоятельные словоформы несовершенного и совершенного вида, поэтому естественным путем образуют деепричастия каждого вида от соответствующей формы (убив (убившись) - убивая, выхлебав (выхлебавши) - выхлебывая). В тех же случаях, когда парная форма несовершенного вида отсутствует, образование деепричастия несовершенного вида невозможно (прочучив(проучившись)- несов. нет, узнав - несов. нет, зазнавшись - несов. нет).

Подведем итог.

> Учась во многих школах, он многое постиг.

Это нормальная конструкция, возможная и для передачи и настоящего, и прошедшего времени. При необходимости различить эти ситуации необходимо использовать дополнительные средства (учась сейчас - учась ранее).

> Учившись во многих школах, он многое постиг.

В современном языке это выглядит грамматическим ахронизмом или стилизацией. Тем не менее можно сказать, что здесь имеется в виду действие, законченное к настоящему моменту, но эффект от которого продолжает сказываться. Таким образом, данную фразу можно трактовать как грамматический окказионализм для передачи отсутствующего в современном русском "продолженного перфекта".